# Booking query does not consider arrival and departure day

Tags: php, mysql

I have been searching for an answer to this dilemma but found nothing. I was hoping you could help to find out what I am doing wrong.

I have a mysql query that selects only apartmens available as follow:

```
SELECT * 
FROM apartments 
WHERE apartment_ID NOT IN (SELECT apartment_ID 
                           FROM bookings 
                           WHERE startDate <= '$endingdate' 
                             AND endDate >= '$startingdate')
```

The problem is that this query is not considering that i.e. departure day is an half day and it is available.

To explain better:

if table "booking" has a booking ending on 16-01-2011 and the search is from the 16-01-2011. The apartment should be available because that is an "half" day (the day of departure). The query seems to not consider this and does not show the apartment.

Please could you help?

Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the = signs from your sub query, or at least the last one if a place vacated on a date is always available on that date. That should check for apartments being vacated on the requested date. Also make sure that your data is escaped.

If availabilty depends on time then you will need to change your date fields to datetimes.

Comment: Hi Belinda, I actually though that the = sign was necessary to select the right starting and ending day. I got rid of it now and it seems to work. Thank you very much. Really appreciated your help

Comment: @Francesco The equals sign checks for less than or equal to or greater than or equal to. You just wanted less that and greater than. You're welcome. Maybe you would consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with MySQL data types , but are you sure that startDate and endDate are not stored with a time part as well. If that's the case then "16-01-2011 16:25" would not be less than or equal to "16-01-2011".

Comment: Hi Bleeeah,No they are stored as "date" without the time part.